# What are the restrictions for spending Play Points?

Tags: google-play-store, google

Does anyone know why spending Play Points is impossible in Poland:

[image]

That was the only reasonable reward I could imagine, but it turned out that I hit the closed door with "Unavailable" label on it. Anyone has any idea how I can open *these* door?

Comment: Play Points program is [available in Poland](https://play.google.com/console/about/programs/googleplaypoints/).

Comment: Thanks! But you're pointing to the developers guide. I don't need an information on how to implement Play Points in my own app, but rather how to resolve the described issue.

Answer (score 1):

This was either a bug:

- In Google Play app in general
- In Google Play service's configuration for my country
- Somewhere in between my account and Google Play service (some glitch)

After filling a two separate Google Play Points Support's reports, of which none has been answered so far (except for repeated information that a problem has been reported to Google Play technician) the whole thing suddenly "un-choked" itself.

Without any change on my side and without any actual information from Google, starting last Saturday I am able to use my Google Points as expected.