# How to browse Play Pass catalogue in Google Play app

Tags: google-play-store

What are the exact steps that I need to undertake in order to see *that famous* "Google Play Pass Catalogue"?

I wanted to see how many games of my interest are currently included.

I went to Google Play app → tap my avatar → Play Pass → *How can I browse the catalogue as a subscriber?*

And (emphasis mine):

> Check out **the Play Pass tab** in the Play Store app or look for games and apps marked with a Play Pass badge throughout the Store.

Since I already was inside Google Play app I pressed *Back* once to get back to the main screen and I saw the following tabs:

- For you
- Top charts
- Children
- Premium
- Categories

Categories includes:

- Action
- Adventure
- Arcade
- Board
- Card
- Casino
- Casual
- Educational
- Music
- Puzzle
- Racing
- Role Playing
- Simulation
- Sports
- Strategy
- Trivia and
- Word.

The same can be selected as a *Categories* filter in *Top charts* tab.

Either I am totally blind or **I see absolutely no traces or tab, category or anything related to *Play Pass***. What am I missing?

Due to my [recent problems with Play Points](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/252044/20449) Google Play app on my phone had both cache and main memory cleared and it was restarted many times. No effect.

Comment: According to the [Google Play Help](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/9473027), there's a link to https://play.google.com/store/pass with the caption "get over 1,000 games and apps". Does it show the list of the apps? Unfortunately, I can't check it because I don't have Play Pass and my country isn't supported; I got redirected to https://play.google/about/play-pass/ instead.

Comment: I also don't have Play Pass and I am also redirected to [play.google/about/play-pass](https://play.google/about/play-pass/) after clicking [play.google.com/store/pass](https://play.google.com/store/pass). Which is really weird, because I am eligible and my country is supported (at least -- it should; given the fact that Google nags me all the time with a willing to take my money in exchange for Play Pass).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Play Store app seems to have been improved recently.

If you are subscribed to Play Pass, you should see a "Play Pass" tab at the bottom, with links to all app and game categories (a bit hidden).

Alternatively, you may use [App Finder](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/app-6-0-app-finder-the-most-advanced-search-engine-for-android-apps.4578809/). It has a filter for the Play Pass, and you can browse a list of nearly/all 1272 Play Pass apps and games with screenshots, short descriptions, and all important data.

You can filter by category, user rating, number of ratings etc.

App Finder is free and without ads, and you don't need to have the Play Pass already.

[Here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/all-play-pass-apps-by-category-and-user-rating-with-data-descriptions-and-screenshots.4618447/) lists of all Play Pass apps (not games) by category.

Comment: I had a similar question ([on not being able to use Play Points](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/252044/20449)) and this was resolved recently. However this particular problem hasn't been solved so far. I still cannot see "Play Pass" tab / category in my Google Play app. Your idea with using App Finder sounds great, so I am accepting your answer. Thank you.